# UIToolbar multiline text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hey guys, I'm trying to add text to my UIToolbar, but there's a catch: I want to change the font and have 2 lines of text (top line smaller, bottom line bigger). Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a bar button item that contains a custom view (which in your case could be a multiline `UILabel`). See `-[UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:]`.